# Lines are not equally spaced in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, line-spacing

I've just move from LaTeX to XeLaTeX, and when I first use it, I found this abnormality :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\newfontfamily{\thai}[Script=Thai]{Norasi}
\begin{document}
{\thai น้องบางคนอาจเคยพบสมการกำลังสามเหล่านี้ และได้พยายามแก้ตามทฤษฎีที่ได้เรียนมาโดย ตั้งสมมติฐาว่าค่า $x$ 
ที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมดคือ ตัวประกอบที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมดของ $d$  หารด้วยตัวประกอบที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมดของ
$a$  หลังจากที่น้องได้ทำการแทนค่าที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมดเหล่านี้แล้วพบว่าสมการก็ยังไม่เป็นจริง หลายคนอาจสรุปทันทีว่าคำตอบ
ของสมการนี้เป็นจำนวนเชิงซ้อน (กรณีนี้รวมถึงสมการที่มีกำลังมากกว่าสามด้วยนะครับ) นั่นเป็นความเข้าใจผิดอย่างเต็มที่เลยครับ
ที่ว่าเข้าใจผิดอย่างเต็มที่ก็เพราะว่าในทฤษฎีกล่าวไว้แต่เพียงว่า คำตอบที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมดเหล่านี้ล้วนแต่เป็นคำตอบที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมด
ของจำนวนตรรกยะเท่านั้น จึงยังไม่ได้ครอบคลุมกรณีที่คำตอบจะเป็นจำนวนอตรรกยะ}

\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system and document markup language. It is widely used for
the communication and publication of scientific documents in many fields, including
mathematics, physics, and computer science. It also has a prominent role in the preparation
and publication of books and articles that contain complex multilingual materials, such
as Sanskrit and Arabic, including critical editions. \LaTeX{} uses the \TeX{} typesetting
program for formatting its output, and is itself written in the \TeX{} macro language.
\LaTeX{} is not the name of a particular editing program, but refers to the encoding
or tagging conventions that are used in \LaTeX{} documents.  (From Wikipedia, the
free encyclopedia)
\end{document}
```

The code above is a 2-paragraph article. One in Thai, and the other in English. And this is the result :
[image]
You can clearly see that line spacing between line 3 and 4 is narrower than others. I think this is because Thai characters have upper and lower punctuation. Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could load the `setspace` package and issue the command `\setstretch{1.25}` for the portions of the document that are in Thai. (If a factor of 1.25 isn't quite enough, 1.30 should do the job, I think.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\newfontfamily{\thai}[Script=Thai]{Norasi}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.25}
{\thai น้องบางคนอาจเคยพบสมการกำลังสามเหล่านี้ และได้พยายามแก้ตามทฤษฎีที่ได้เรียนมาโดย ตั้งสมมติฐาว่าค่า $x$ 
ที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมดคือ ตัวประกอบที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมดของ $d$  หารด้วยตัวประกอบที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมดของ
$a$  หลังจากที่น้องได้ทำการแทนค่าที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมดเหล่านี้แล้วพบว่าสมการก็ยังไม่เป็นจริง หลายคนอาจสรุปทันทีว่าคำตอบ
ของสมการนี้เป็นจำนวนเชิงซ้อน (กรณีนี้รวมถึงสมการที่มีกำลังมากกว่าสามด้วยนะครับ) นั่นเป็นความเข้าใจผิดอย่างเต็มที่เลยครับ
ที่ว่าเข้าใจผิดอย่างเต็มที่ก็เพราะว่าในทฤษฎีกล่าวไว้แต่เพียงว่า คำตอบที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมดเหล่านี้ล้วนแต่เป็นคำตอบที่เป็นไปได้ทั้งหมด
ของจำนวนตรรกยะเท่านั้น จึงยังไม่ได้ครอบคลุมกรณีที่คำตอบจะเป็นจำนวนอตรรกยะ}

\singlespacing % or: \setstretch{1.0}
\LaTeX{} is a document preparation system and document markup language. It is widely used for
the communication and publication of scientific documents in many fields, including
mathematics, physics, and computer science. It also has a prominent role in the preparation
and publication of books and articles that contain complex multilingual materials, such
as Sanskrit and Arabic, including critical editions. \LaTeX{} uses the \TeX{} typesetting
program for formatting its output, and is itself written in the \TeX{} macro language.
\LaTeX{} is not the name of a particular editing program, but refers to the encoding
or tagging conventions that are used in \LaTeX{} documents.  (From Wikipedia, the
free encyclopedia)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The spacing between lines is determined by `\baselineskip`. The default value is `12pt`; setting it higher (say `14pt`) should ensure uniformity of line spacing. The best way to set this is in the definition of `\normalsize`, the default font size for the document, by putting

```
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12}{18}\selectfont}
```

in your document preamble.

Comment: Thanks for response. But with no luck, the space is still narrow. I think `\XeTeXlinebreakskip` is for linebreaking because Thai words aren't separated by space. As I adjusted this value, the line breaking become ugly :(.

Comment: Sorry, my first answer was wrong; I've completely changed it so that it works now.

Comment: Since the MWE's main font size is 12pt, should you maybe use `\fontsize{12}{18}`?

Comment: I wish I could accept both answer, but I couldn't. Thank you so much.